# Breakout game math - angle to dx,dy

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, game-physics

I am making a basic javascript game of breakout but I have not really learned math yet so I'm having some issues..

I want to have the ball hit the paddle and get bounced off at an angle dependant on where it hits the paddle.

I just made this function that calculates an angle from 0-180 degrees when the ball hits the paddle. That angle is what the ball will need to move at (I know right now that will be an issue if the ball hits the tip of the paddle, but I'll deal with that later) Now I need to find a way to get a dx and dy from that, and I know I will need to use trigonometry to do so. (x is the variable for the ball's x coordinate)

```
function getBallAngle(){
const maxAngle = 180;
let hitPosition = (x - paddleX);
let ballAngle = 0;
const scaleToAngle = maxAngle / (paddleWidth); 

ballAngle = hitPosition * scaleToAngle;

return ballAngle; }
```

I'm a bit lost right now, would appreciate some math help please.

edit: I already have the game working but without this feature that would change the angle the ball bounces off the paddle.

Comment: Your math, at the moment, will result in the same outbound angle when the ball strikes the same point on the paddle irrespective of the inbound angle. In order to properly calculate an outbound angle, you truly need to know the inbound angle.

Comment: In Javascript angles are in radians. To convert from deg to rad  `angleRadians = angleDeg * (Math.PI / 180)`  When you have an angle in radians you can get the `dx`, `dy` of that angle with `dx = Math.cos(angleRadians)` and `dy = Math.sin(angleRadians)` Zero deg is to the right at  3oclock. If you only have dx and dy and want the angle in radians  `angleRadians = Math.atan2(dy,dx)`  with dy first

Comment: Oh and if you want the ball as a speed `speed` then `dx = Math.cos(angleRadians) * speed;` and `dy = Math.sin(angleRadians) * speed;`

Comment: Thanks :) that seems to work although it is reflecting off the paddle the opposite angle of what I had in mind and behaves really oddly when hitting the tip of the paddle but I kind of expected that, and should be able to fix from here. tyvm

Answer (score 1):

Consider the moving ball has having both an `x` and a `y` component (as you implied with your request for `dx` and `dy`). Since you are writing this in javascript, these values can be assigned to your `ball` object so that they can be referenced on every tick (i.e. every time your program calculates the current state of the game and re-renders all display objects).

Assuming, for the moment, that we are only dealing with the paddle then we can assume that when the ball strikes the paddle the horizontal movement factor (the `x`) will not change (we don't want the ball careening backwards off the paddle.. except in the literal edge case..). And since we are treating the paddle like a reflective surface, the vertical movement factor (the `y`) will simply switch from moving in a downward fashion to an upward fashion (accomplished most easily via multiplication by `-1`).

Therefore, the "angle" that you are looking for is actually just a reversal of the `y` component of your ball's movement property.

Comment: I want the same outbound angle when the ball strikes the same spot on the paddle to give the game variation. Without that x never changes and the game executes the same way every time assuming the player never misses a ball. Thanks though.